# Возможно ли добавить Task в работающий event_loop вне цикла

Tags: python, asyncio

Пытаюсь добавить task в работающий цикл извне. Пример нерабочего кода:

```
class Handler:
task = False
async def print_while(self, text):
    while True:
        print(text)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
async def main(self, loop):
    while True:
        if self.task:
            loop.create_task(self.task)
            self.task = False
        else:
            print('Nesmogla ya')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

obj = Handler()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(obj.main(loop))
loop.run_forever()

obj.task = obj.print_while('Second task')
```

Я уверен, что делаю что-то не верно, но найти хороший пример для добавления/приостановления/удаления задачи извне цикла  найти не могу

Comment: Вы же `obj.task` присваиваете после окончания цикла...

Comment: Да. В том то и делом, мне нужно добавлять задачи в уже рабочий цикл. По факту: сервер с помощью GET запроса от клиента получает IP, который сразу нужно ставить на пинг. Пинг - задача в  бесконечном цикле. Задача эта должна добавляться уже в работающий с другими пингами-задачами  event_loop. Надеюсь было понятно

Comment: Ну так и добавляйте задачу в рабочий цикл, а не в завершившийся!

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, в том то и дело, цикл не завершается. Он постоянно работает, т.к. все задачи с бесконечным циклом. Я просто не могу найти способа достучаться извне в работающий event_loop. В вышеизложенном коде я описал подход, который использую. Он неверный. Вы не могли бы привести простой пример, либо указать ссылку на полезную информацию, которая поможет решить вопрос?

Comment: У вас есть функция main. Перенесите `obj.print_while('Second task')` внутрь - вот вам и пример будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov то бишь создать таск из уже работающего таска. Вот работает у меня теперь два таска в бесконечном цикле , друг другу дают возможность работать, и основной цикл еще не закончил работать, а уже пришел от сервера запрос печатать слово "арбузик". Как же мне добавить задачу print_while('арбузик') без завершения основного цикла программным способом?

Comment: Ну и зачем вам бесконечный цикл-то?

Comment: Начните с того, что напишите код запроса к серверу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это задача для постоянного пинга множества ip-адресов с небольшим интервалом. Порядка 100 ip по мере возможности будут пинаться по 40 пакетов каждые 60 секунд. Все это дело может работать до 2х суток без перерыва. Поэтому мне кажется не целесообразно цикл завершать каждый раз. Но скорее всего придется основной луп останавливать при добавлении или удалении задачи

Comment: У вас в процессе работы список ip-адресов не может измениться просто так, сам по себе. У всего есть причина.

Comment: Вопрос вероятно вызван простым недопониманием самых самых основ async. Решение должно быть тривиальным. Но не ясно что вы хотите чтобы код делал. Попробуйте искусственный *минимальный* пример создать. Опишите его в терминах желаемого *наблюдаемого* поведения. Приведите вашу попытку решения, явно опишите как поведение от желаемого отличается. [mcve]

Comment: Действительно отсутствовало понимание основ. Я решил задачу с помощью остановки лупа, внесения изменений список задач и запуска лупа заново.

Comment: остановка лупа?) серьёзно? Код который останавливает луп - плохой код. Вы же можете делать сколько угодно `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` и вешать на него таск без остановки..

Answer (score 0):

Из коментариев почти понял что нужно реализовать.

```
class Netflow5(asyncio.DatagramProtocol):

    def __init__(self,*a,**kw):
        super(Netflow5,self).__init__(*a,**kw)
        self._waiter = asyncio.Event()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._flush_future = loop.create_task(self.store())    


    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        if data[1] == 5:
            self.process(data, addr)

    async def store(self):
        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(self._waiter.wait(), timeout=FLUSHINTERVAL)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                pass
            try:
                await self.store_once()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)
            self._waiter.clear()

t = asyncio.Task(loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
    Netflow5, local_addr=(HOST,PORT)))

logger.debug("task set")
transport, server = loop.run_until_complete(t)
logger.debug("started")
```

store выполняет store_once по независимо от приёма UDP от устройств. Сброс waiter-а вместо sleep чтоб не блокировалось.